# C# Unknown column 'Extent1.UserId' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to model my database and I'm having some issues. I have these two tables: ProductSetting and User. ProductSetting looks something like this:

```
ProductSettingId
ProductType
CreatedByUserId
```

CreatedByUserId has a foreign key set with the user table on the column "user_id"

User table is like this

```
UserId
Name
```

And my ProductUnitSetting class

```
public class ProductUnitSetting
{
    [Key, Column("product_setting_id"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("product_type"), Required]
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }             

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Column("created_by_user_id"), Required]        
    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

}
```

And my User Class:

```
[Table("user")]
public class User
{
    [Key, Column("user_id"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

So when I run this, I get the error:

```
Unknown column 'Extent1.UserId' in 'field list'

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column     'Extent1.UserId' in 'field list'
```

And I've tried many things including putting an InverseProperty in the user class like:

```
[InverseProperty("created_by_user_id")]
public virtual ProductUnitSetting ProductUnitSetting { get; set; }
```

but it doesn't work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does `Extent1` and `field list` look familiar ? are these declared somewhere in your code ? If so, please post their declarations as well.

Comment: Extent1 is a table alias used by entity framework

Comment: please post the sql of the query you are executing as well. The query in which this alias is defined (are we talking about an entity framework generated query or something you wrote ?)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[ForeignKey("User")]
public int UserId { get; set; }             

public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, it's saying to do pretty much the same as the above, which I did but I"m still getting the same error. Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.